# Disable cache and 301/302 redirect caching in Apache Traffic Server

Tags: apache, redirect, caching, apache-traffic-server

I'm using Apache Traffic server primarily as an easily configurable reverse proxy.

I have disabled caching completely for some of virtual machines by adding entries in cache.config

```
dest_domain=mydomain.tld scheme=http action=never-cache
```

**Does this disable all object caching?**

**Why does this not disable redirect caching?**

(I have to clear the Trafficserver cache in order to clear stale 301 redirects)

I know this is a bit of an edge-case (I'd usually not encounter 301 caching issues) - but I ran into this today and I was surprised it was still caching redirects and I could not find any documentation on *how* Trafficserver caches redirects, for how long etc.